# Private Chat Hub with Real-Time Message Updates without reloading

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, signalr

I have developed a private chat hub where users can log in and see a list of other users. Next to each user's name, there is a chat button.

When a user clicks on the chat button, they are redirected to a chat page where they can start sending messages. However, there is a current issue where the messages only appear to the sender, and the receiver must reload the page to view the messages from the database.

I'm looking for a solution to make the messages appear in real-time for the receiver as well.

Chathub

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using DashBoard1.Models;

namespace DashBoard1.Hubs
{
   
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();



        public async Task SendMessage(string sender, string receiver, string message)
        {

            var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email.ToLower() == receiver.ToLower());

            if (user != null)
            {
                var userId = user.Id;
                var chatMessage = new ChatViewModel()
                {
                    SenderEmail = sender,
                    ReceiverEmail = receiver,
                    Message = message,
                    SentAt = DateTime.Now
                };
                db.Chat.Add(chatMessage);
                db.SaveChanges();

                await Clients.Caller.sendMessage(sender, message);
                await Clients.User(userId).sendMessage(sender, message);
                await Clients.User(userId).updateChat();
            }
        }


    }
    }
```

ChatView

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Chat";
}

<h2>Chat</h2>
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="message" />
    <input type="button" id="sendMessage" value="Send" />
    <input type="hidden" id="senderEmail" value="@ViewBag.currentUser" />
    <input type="hidden" id="receiverEmail" value="@ViewBag.receiverEmail" />

    <ul id="messageList">
        @{foreach (var message in Model)
            {
                <li><strong>@message.SenderEmail</strong>: @message.Message</li>
            }
        }
    </ul>
</div>

@section scripts {
    <!--Script references. -->
    <!--The jQuery library is required and is referenced by default in _Layout.cshtml. -->
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--SignalR script to update the chat page and send messages.-->

    <script>
        $(function () {
            // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

            // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
            chat.client.sendMessage = function (sender, message) {
                // Add the message to the page
                $('#messageList').append('<li><strong>' + htmlEncode(sender) + '</strong>: ' + htmlEncode(message) + '</li>');
                $('#messageList').scrollTop($('#messageList')[0].scrollHeight);
          
            };


            // Set initial focus to message input box.
            $('#message').focus();

            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                
                $('#sendMessage').click(function () {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub.
                    chat.server.sendMessage($('#senderEmail').val(), $('#receiverEmail').val(), $('#message').val());
                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
                chat.client.updateChat = function () {
                    // Reload the page to retrieve the updated messages from the database
                    location.reload();
                };
            });
        });

        // This optional function html-encodes messages for display in the page.
        function htmlEncode(value) {
            var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();
            return encodedValue;
        }
    </script>


}
```

ChatActionMethod

```
  [Authorize(Roles = "Accountant")]
        public ActionResult Chat(string receiverEmail)
        {
            var currentUser = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()).Email;
            ViewBag.currentUser = currentUser;
            ViewBag.receiverEmail = receiverEmail;
            var messages = _context.Chat.Where(m => (m.SenderEmail == currentUser && m.ReceiverEmail == receiverEmail) || (m.SenderEmail == receiverEmail && m.ReceiverEmail == currentUser)).ToList();

            return View(messages);
        }
```

Users list

```
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Chat", "Chat", "Home", new { receiverEmail = item.Email }, new { @class = "chat-button" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
```

AccountantActionMethod

```
//public ActionResult AccountantIndex(int clientid)
      [Authorize(Roles = "Accountant")]
      public ActionResult Accountants()
      {
          var currentUser = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
          ViewBag.currentUser = currentUser;
          var accountants = _context.Users.Where(u => u.Id != currentUser.Id && u.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == "ba28c9e7-414b-489b-99e7-d97fd4ade08b")).ToList();
 
          return View(accountants);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Way i would do this is when the message has been sent, get signal r to broadcast a message to the other person and then when that has been recieved refresh messages. i know your using js but heres a c# version:

when sending:

```
await Clients.Client("").SendAsync("newMessageSent");
```

update on recieve message:

```
hubConnection.On("newMessageSent", async () => { //update chat });
```

you could use that as a base and do in js if you would like

Comment: i will try it thank you but in client don't i need to declare a connection?

Comment: yea you will, sorry i didnt put it in, will be connection ID of whoever you are sending the message to @MohamedEssam